# Javascript with parameters of function into innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters, innerhtml

I have a big problem, when I passing parameters to a function into innerHTML-

I want to delete an row that name is Riga1 when the user click the hyperlink

This is the code:

```
div.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Riga "+ContaRigheFoglio+" "+"Colonna "+i+"' style='width:100px;'><a href='#' onClick='EliminaRiga("Riga1")' class='piu'>+</a><a href='#' class='meno'>-</a><div id='Finale Riga "+ContaRigheFoglio+" "+"Colonna "+i+"' class='IntestazioneCasella' style='display:none;width: auto;text-align: center;margin-left: 10px;'></div>";
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a place to ask for code to accomplish your goal. Questions should be regarding a specific issue and include code giving a reasonable attempt. Your issue would be more appropriate as a work request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding into the parenthesis this code:

```
  &#39;Riga1&#39;
```

Comment: You do not need to mark the title with "Solved". Just post your answer and accept it. If this is the case